# on back button previous activity won't get updated with new data

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

I have two activities `profile_Activity` and `Edit_Profile_activity` when I am moving from `Profile_Activity` to `Edit_Profile_activity` and doing some changes on profile and update the profile, Activity updates successfully but updated values are not shown on `profile_Activity` when the back button of mobile is pressed. also the value is shown on press UpEnabled button.

Comment: make a common class with getter setter.set values from edit activity and get values in profile activity.

Comment: How you are updating your Profile Activity

Comment: @Rahul m using Volley response method on Update button click listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start activity by using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, Edit_Profile_activity.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);


 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
                    String abc=data.getStringExtra("data_key")    ;            
                   //write your code for update info
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

In your Edit_Profile_activity return result by using

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.putExtra("data_key",value);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```